# tensorflow word2vec: parameters and preprocessing

Tags: tensorflow, word2vec, word-embedding

I'm using the word2vec_basic from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py and I have a few (general) questions.

How should I determine the `num_steps`? In the example it is set to 100001.

Is a `skip_window` of 5 enough or should it be bigger (10, 25)?

Also, should stopwords and punctuation be removed from the training dataset and should all words be converted to lower case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Generally more the `num_steps`, better the model is. You can start with one value of `num_steps`, and use it as a benchmark against different values. You can plot `loss` vs `num_steps` and see if your loss is really decreasing after some threshold value of `num_steps` parameter.

Choosing `skip_window` depends on the type of dataset you are choosing. If window size of 5 can capture the context of a word, but if 10 is chosen, it will decrease the quality of the learned model, and vice versa.

Let's take an example. Consider the following sentence - *"Tensorflow great framework for machine-learning for the programmers."* If the window size is 2, then the vector of word '**Tensorflow**' is directly affected by the word '**great**' and '**framework**', but if the window size is 5 '**Tensorflow**' can be directly affected by two more words - '**for**' and '**machine-learning**'. Hence, it will pull the vector of two words closer.

And, as far as stopwords are concerned, I would recommend to remove the stopwords and punctuation marks and convert the words to lowercase as they add noise to the dataset and doesn't carry much importance with the context word.

You can have a look at this [link](http://mccormickml.com/2016/04/12/googles-pretrained-word2vec-model-in-python/) for better understanding the data used by Google to train word2vec model.

Comment: @daria I updated my answer as per my learnings, please check if it helps.